# Error on String.Format

Tags: asp.net

I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on the line "welcome.Text = ...."

Home:

```
protected void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UserNameTextBox.Text != String.Empty)
    {
        Session["UserName"] = UserNameTextBox.Text;
        Label welcome = (Label)Master.FindControl("GreetingLabel");
        welcome.Text = String.Format("Welcome, {0}!", Session["UserName"]);
    }
}

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Professional.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <br /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="UserNameTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="SitePrefDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Professional" Value="Professional"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Colourful" Value="Colourful"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="OK" onclick="OKButton_Click" />

</asp:Content>
```

I got the code from MCTS Exam 70-515 Web Dev book.

I looked at the Errata page, no luck.  http://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780735627406

Master Page:

```
public partial class Professional : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["UserName"] != null)
        {
            GreetingLabel.Text = String.Format("Welcome, {0}!", Session["UserName"]);
        }
    }
}

<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Professional.master.cs" Inherits="Professional" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <img src="Contoso.gif"  /><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Welcome to Contoso!" 
                Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label>



        &nbsp;<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Products" Value="Products"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Services" Value="Services"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Downloads" Value="Downloads"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="About Us" Value="About Us"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>



        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">

            <asp:Label ID="GreetingLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards
LF

Comment: Where is the `GreetingLabel` control located in the master? If it's in a `ContentPlaceHolder` the `NamingContainer` is that not the master.

Comment: Can you debug, what's in that Session["UserName"]?

Comment: Tim:  it is in a Master.  Under <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">

Comment: Both @TimSchmelter and ValidfroM do have a point. Set a breakpoint at that line and check which of the two is null.

Comment: ValidfroM: a name "LF"

Comment: welcome says it's null

Comment: See @TimSchmelter 's answer. ;-)

Comment: Right, I've copied the entire code of the next Exercise from the CD, that works, so I'll stick to that.  Thanks for the help. Not sure what the problem was, but doesn't matter.

Comment: (this book in terms of errors is poor btw.  Never seen so many errors in one technical book)

Answer (score 1):

Where is the `GreetingLabel` control located in the master? If it's in a `ContentPlaceHolder` the `NamingContainer` is that not the master.

You: "it is in a Master, under":

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
```

That's it, you first have to find the `ContentPlaceHolder`, then use `FindControl` on it:

```
var cPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("MainContent");
Label welcome = (Label)cPlaceHolder.FindControl("GreetingLabel");
```

Now you don't get a `NullReferenceException` on  `welcome.Text` anymore:

```
welcome.Text = String.Format("Welcome, {0}!", Session["UserName"]);
```

**Edit** Since you have commented that it still doesn't work for whatever reason. I will suggest a different - better - approach. Provide a public property in your `Master`, for example `Greeetings`. Then you can get/set the `Label.Text` via this property. That is much more readable and maintainable. It will also work even if you change the label to a different control like `TextBox` or `Div`.

For example (in the `MasterPage` of type `Professional`):

```
public string Greetings
{
    get { return GreetingLabel.Text;  }
    set { GreetingLabel.Text = value; }
}
```

Now you can cast the `Master` property in your content-page to `Professional` to access it:

```
Professional professional = (Professional) this.Master;
professional.Greetings = String.Format("Welcome, {0}!", Session["UserName"]);
```

Comment: @user2776489: Have you seen that i've corected my code to use `FindControl("MainContent")` instead of `FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1")`? However, you have to use the correct ID of the `ContentPlaceHolder`. But you should show us the aspx code of the master.

Comment: Tim: See my comments on main post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

see this

```
welcome.Text = String.Format("Welcome, {0}!", Session["UserName"]);// replace Session["UserName"] with Session["UserName"].ToString()
```

now your new line is

```
welcome.Text = String.Format("Welcome, {0}!", Session["UserName"].ToString());
```